# How can I concatenate arrays of 2D data

Tags: c++, arrays, c++98

I am attempting to read 2D data like the following:

```
12345678
abcdefgh
ABCDEFGH
```

With the API available to me, I can read it into a 1D array in two parts, split down the middle:

First array: `1234abcdABCD`

Second array: `5678efghEFGH`

Now I need to merge these to get `12345678abcdefghABCDEFGH`.

Is there a more sophisticated/stable way of doing this than `memcpy` and careful counting?

Comment: Does the order of the triplets matter? (i.e. would somthing like 132acbACB be an acceptable output?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence of inserts can do the job. The code can be extracted into a function that takes a number of chunks and chunk size as parameters.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> my_merge(
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& part1,
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& part2,
    const unsigned int chunk_count, 
    const unsigned int chunk_size)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> merged;
    merged.reserve(part1.size() + part2.size());
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < chunk_count; ++i)
    {
        merged.insert(
            merged.end(), 
            part1.begin() + i * chunk_size, 
            part1.begin() + (i + 1) * chunk_size);
        merged.insert(
            merged.end(), 
            part2.begin() + i * chunk_size, 
            part2.begin() + (i + 1) * chunk_size);
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> merged = my_merge(part1, part2, 3, 4);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KNQCnzNaZ9HVTKvp)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try `std::copy`.

example below (may be you can rewrite below code by looping logically).

```
int a[12] = {1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d','A','B','C','D'};
int b[12] = {5,6,7,8,'e','f','g','h','E','F','G','H'};

int c[3][8];

//First Row
std::copy(a, a+4, c[0]);
std::copy(b, b+4, c[0]+4);

//Second Row
std::copy(a+4, a+8, c[1]);
std::copy(b+4, b+8, c[1]+4);

//Third Row
std::copy(a+8, a+12, c[2]);
std::copy(b+8, b+12, c[2]+4);
```